# Using PHP cURL to get OAuth access/authorization code

Tags: php, curl, oauth-2.0

I am using PHP with cURL to retrieve an OAuth token.  My code below works to get the access token, however, I am wondering how to retrieve the return authorization code without using a page refresh with header (the first step).

Here is the workflow:
Request the access code via header and _GET.  Use the access code to get the token.

QUESTION:  Can I do this using cURL to get the access/authorization code instead of using  header('Location: '.$url); and a $_GET["code"]; ???

```
$url = AUTH_URL."?"
 ."response_type=code"
 ."&client_id=". urlencode(CLIENT_ID)
 ."&scope=". urlencode(SCOPE)
 ."&redirect_uri=". urlencode(CALLBACK_URL)
;

if (isset($_GET["code"]))
{
  $code = $_GET["code"];
  print "CODE: $code<br>";
  getToken($code);

}
else
{
  header('Location: '.$url);
}

function getToken($code){
    
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, ACCESS_TOKEN_URL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [ 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query([
        'code'          => $code,
        'client_id'     => CLIENT_ID,
        'client_secret' => CLIENT_SECRET,
        'redirect_uri'  => CALLBACK_URL,
        'grant_type'    => 'authorization_code',
    ]));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $access_token = $response['access_token'];
```

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:** No.

**Long answer:**

The whole point of OAuth is to not have to deal with user credentials. You define an idp [identity provider] that you trust to authenticate your users, redirect them there to do their authentication, and then the user returns to your callback URL with a single-use token that you can validate with the idp.

What you are essentially asking for is to have the user entrust you with their idp credentials and for you to authenticate on their behalf. This not only negates the whole point of using OAuth, but also saddles you with having to securely manage users' credentials to a service that is not your own.

All the hassle of OAuth *and* internal auth combined, *and* being responsible for the keys to all of your users' respective kingdoms, *and* if the users figure out what you're doing [which they can't not] they will burn you at the stake.

Comment: You are making assumptions that are not true.  I can't get an Oauth token for a user If not already logged in with another browser tab,.  This is just for me for my admin purposes.  I would be already logged into the site in another tab,

Comment: The answer is still no. Your _browser_ is authenticated with your idp, but your _server_ is not.